# Makehuman clothes missing faces

Tags: faces, makehuman

I have been using makehuman for a while and when I import certain objects I have issues. The biggest one im experiencing is missing faces. All vertex show up. In fact kode there is nothing. I tried clicking on missing faces, they simply do not exist. It will take forever to recreate all faces. Looking for a better solution.

What I tried.

1. Reverse normals, no existing normals to reverse.
2. File, extrrnal data, make all paths absolute.
3. Made sure blackface culling was off, exported as obj and reloaded same issue.
4. Retopolgize, mesh completely disappears

Also with transparent hair texture, I cant get that to work right either. Put transparency value to 1 and o. Nogo.  (Fixed)

Please help.

Image 1 is what it looks like in makehuman, image 2 is with it selected, showing no faces

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Dao.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Dao.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utybk.jpg)[image][image][image]

Comment: Hi. Judging by what you wrote, it looks like you intended to upload some images. Did you forget to upload them?

Comment: Yes sorry, still not fixed.

Comment: Hmmm. It's still very hard to tell what's going on. Any chance you could upload the .blend file? You can do it here if you want - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/